# iOS xCode 6. Load small app's at needed time in the app which contains them

Tags: ios, objective-c, bundle, xcode6.1

I have a project which is consisting of a small app's [like this](http://postimg.org/image/u1naatdpp/). Earlier, that project had main App that contained those small app's  and loaded them when it was needed. Unfortunately, I don't have a full project on my hands and I need to recreate the behaviour in which the whole project was working. I have created an app which is ready to act as a container of sub app's.

I found out about [Dynamically Loading Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/LoadingCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000052-SW1) guide, but instruction in the `Creating Loadable Bundle` section  is seems to be out of date. Because, I could't follow described steps in the xCode 6.1, to create `bundle` project from scratch to just try if it will work.

However, maybe you can tell some ways where should I put sub app's and how I can load each app when I need it, please?